# How configure zabbix to receive data?

Tags: java, zabbix

I have create a host with name `dev002-All-Series`, added [tapper item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper) to it with key `test.ping.count` add host and ip addres to allowed hosts. Then I try to send a data with [zabbix-metrics library](https://github.com/hengyunabc/metrics-zabbix) with code like that:

```
private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;
private Meter pingMeter;

private void init() {
    metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry();
    metricRegistry.register("jvm.attribute.guage.set", new JvmAttributeGaugeSet());
    ZabbixSender zabbixSender = new ZabbixSender("zabbixHost", 10051);
    ZabbixReporter zabbixReporter = ZabbixReporter.forRegistry(metricRegistry)
            .hostName(HostUtil.getHostName()).prefix("test.").build(zabbixSender);

    //FIXME us right time unit and amount
    zabbixReporter.start(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    pingMeter = metricRegistry.meter("ping");
}
```

Note that zabbix-metrics library surrond `ping` meter with `test.` prefix and `.count` posyfix. 
So why I hae receive that I have failed to send my data? The response is:

```
{"response":"success","info":"processed: 0; failed: 8; total: 8; seconds spent: 0.000013"}
```

What is neccesary configure in addition in zabbix to send data? Also is there a way to the reason why zabbix do not receive data - does is logs such requests?

Answer (score 0):

Possible popular reasons:

- incorrect host name; make sure to match the "Host name" field (not "Visible name", not IP, not DNS...); note that it is case sensitive
- incorrect item key; make sure it matches the one in the item key properties *exactly* - also case sensitive
- incorrect allowed host field contents, or data coming from a different host than expected - check that field for syntax errors, remember that in older Zabbix versions spaces are not supported in that field and tcpdump your incoming connection - does it arrive from the host you expected ?
- host/item not in the configuration cache - if you just added or changed host/item, it might not be in the config cache yet. The config cache is updated every 60 seconds by default
- if the host is monitored by a Zabbix proxy, you must send data to that proxy

In general, forget your application for a moment and test with [zabbix_sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manpages/zabbix_sender). If that works, check what is your application doing differently. If that fails, check all the items above.

As for logging, currently Zabbix does not log failures or their reasons.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply the infomation is very usefull, but the problem was in java library. By the way, do you know the answer to [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414872/why-zabbix-do-not-show) zabbix question?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem. It turns that metrics zabbix library do not convert data well (for version 0.0.1). It send clock value as `long` in milliseconds, while zabbix needs to receive it in **seconds**. After manual converting I got:

```
{"response":"success","info":"processed: 2; failed: 0; total: 2; seconds spent: 0.000016"}
```

I it very funy that even when I got 2 successful processed elements, zabbix do not show any values at graphic.

**UPDATED**

To get all works you should check not only clock in data object, but clock in reqeust too. By default `metrics zabbix` uses `zabbix-sedner` version `0.0.1` which send clocks in milliseconds. To make metrics works with zabbix 3.0 which expect clock time in seconds you should change `zabbix-sedner` version to 0.0.3. Here is a maven sample:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.hengyunabc</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-zabbix</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.hengyunabc</groupId>
  <artifactId>zabbix-sender</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38418644/1251549)