# Why zabbix do not show a value received from java code?

Tags: java, zabbix

Consider a java code:

```
    String host = "zabbixHost";
    int port = 10051;
    ZabbixSender zabbixSender = new ZabbixSender(host, port);

    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
    dataObject.setHost("testHost");
    dataObject.setKey("test.ping.count");
    dataObject.setValue("10");
    // TimeUnit is SECONDS.
    dataObject.setClock(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    SenderResult result = zabbixSender.send(dataObject);

    System.out.println("result:" + result);
    if (result.success()) {
        System.out.println("send success.");
    } else {
        System.err.println("sned fail!");
    }
```

The result is `{"failed":0,"processed":1,"spentSeconds":0.001715,"total":1}`

Then I send a request by `zabbix_sender` tool from command line:

```
zabbix_sender -z zabbixHost -p 10051 -s testHost -k test.ping.count -o 8 -v
```

The output is:

```
info from server: "processed: 1; failed: 0; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.002052"
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1
```

For now 2 values were sent into Zabbix. But when I got to the monitoring graphic for `test.ping.count` and only `8` value is shown. E.g. value from java code was not received even when response was successful.

What is going on? How to fix such situation?

*Note*

The library is - `io.github.hengyunabc:zabbix-sender:0.0.3`
Zabbix version is 3.0

Comment: Where exactly and how exactly are you checking the values? If it is graph, do you see it if you switch to values (upper right corner)? If still not, do both values show up if you drag the time period scrollbar to the rightmost edge and the click "All" for the time period selection? If still not, do you see both values for that item in the database? If you see them in the database, it might be a bug in Zabbix: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-9236

Comment: Could you please tell or share a link where to see zabbix database connetion settings?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with timestamps, zabbix-sender with version `0.0.1` set **request** (not dataobject) clock in milliseconds while version `0.0.3` in seconds. So using right version fix issues.

maven sample ([source](https://github.com/hengyunabc/metrics-zabbix/issues/2)):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.hengyunabc</groupId>
        <artifactId>zabbix-sender</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```